# Perfect complexes on a formal scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a quasi separated, quasi compact scheme, $Z$ be a closed subscheme on $X$. We denote by $\hat{X}$ the formal scheme of $X$ along $Z$.

My questions are the following.

(1) How to define the stable infinity category $\text{perf}(\hat{X})$ of perfect complexes on $\hat{X}$.
(2) Assume $x$ is proper over an affine scheme $S$. Is there the Grothendieck existence theorem for perfect complexes on $\hat{X}$? i.e, any perfect complex on $\hat{X}$ comes from a perfect complex on $X_n$?

Comment: Re (1): perfect complexes are defined on any ringed space \[Tag [08CL](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08CL)\] or ringed topos \[Tag [08G4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08G4)\]. For (2), I only know a reference \[Tag [0DIA](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DIA)\] in the setting of proper schemes over a complete local ring (and it's not explicitly about perfect complexes, only pseudo-coherent). But I'm far from an expert, so I hope someone else can say more.